# Google+ URL being changed when clicked from WP site

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

I am working on a WordPress site and the Google+ profile URL is being changed when it is clicked on.

To be more specific, the + sign within the URL is being changed to %20 so it is opening up a 404 page on Google.

Please can anyone tell me how to stop WP from changing the + sign into a %20 within external URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You are best to encode the plus sign. A plus sign is represented by `%2B`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Thanks Rick. All sorted and working fine. Funny I have never had this issue with any other site but at least it is sorted now.

Comment: it's always the little things :)